# Proving a sum of a polynomial is convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $p(x)$ be a nonzero polynomial. I want to prove that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{p(n)}{a^n}$ in convergent for every $a>1$. I thought it might be useful to prove that $lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{p(n)}=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. The polynomial has just finitely many terms. Think about 
$$
\frac{n^d}{a^n}$$

when $d$ and $a$ are fixed and $n$ is large.

Answer (score 0):

That's very helpful Ethan!
Now, if I assume that I've proven that $\sqrt[n]{n^d}=1$, then from the root test:
$limSup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{n^d}{a^n}}=\frac{1}{a}<1$ and therfore the series $\sum_{n}^
{\infty}\frac{n^d}{a^n}$ converges. Then I can wrute the polynomial as $p(n)=a_in^i+a_{i-1}n^{i-1}+...+a_0$ and then:
$\sum_{n}^{\infty}\frac{p(n)}{a^n}=\sum_{n}^{\infty}\frac{a_in^i+a_{i-1}n^{i-1}+...+a_0}{a^n}=\sum_{n}^{\infty}{\frac{a_in^i}{a^n}+\frac{a_{i-1}n^{i-1}}{a^n}+...+\frac{a_0}{a^n}}=\sum_{n}^{\infty}{\frac{a_in^i}{a^n}}+\sum_{n}^{\infty}{\frac{a_{i-1}n^{i-1}}{a^n}}+...+\sum_{n}^{\infty}{\frac{a_0}{a^n}}$ and as we've shown each of these sums converge.
Is this correct?